# Передать объект на чистом JS с помощью AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно передать объект на чистом JS, без какого бы то ни было JQuery средствами AJAX?

UPD: а почему возникает 405 ошибка?

В запрос добавил:

```
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET,POST,OPTIONS');'
```

Но не помогло.

Comment: передать куда? какой объект?

Comment: Обычный JS объект, включающий 4 свойства-строки, на сервер.

Comment: Как справочная информация, очень много про xmlhttprequest, если интересно: http://xmlhttprequest.ru/

Comment: [405 status code](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#405)

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
var data = ...
var method = "POST" // или GET
var url = ...

httpReq(url, method, data, function(res) {
    console.log("response: ", res);
});

function getXmlHttp() {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

function httpReq(URL, method, data, success, error) {
    var request = getXmlHttp();
    request.open(method, URL, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // application/x-www-form-urlencoded - для передачи urlencoded данных
    // Для FormData использовать multipart/form-data
    request.send(data);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                success(request.responseText);
            }
            else {
                if (error) error(request.status);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой конструктор XMLHttpRequest, почитать можно например тут - https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest. Пример использования, взятый из статьи по ссылке:

```js
/ 1. Создаём новый объект XMLHttpRequest
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// 2. Конфигурируем его: GET-запрос на URL 'phones.json'
xhr.open('GET', 'phones.json', false);

// 3. Отсылаем запрос
xhr.send();

// 4. Если код ответа сервера не 200, то это ошибка
if (xhr.status != 200) {
  // обработать ошибку
  alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); // пример вывода: 404: Not Found
} else {
  // вывести результат
  alert( xhr.responseText ); // responseText -- текст ответа.
}
```

Comment: Мне бы хороший пример.

Comment: поиск же есть. Примеров на сайте миллион

Comment: Он, к сожалению, только JQuery выдает.

Comment: Помилуйте, батенька. Ищем слово *XMLHttpRequest*

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 obj={
     param1:"1",
     param2:"2"
} 
xhr.open('POST',"/ajaxtest.php",  false);

xhr.send(obj);

if (xhr.status != 200) {
  alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); 
} else {
  alert( xhr.responseText ); // responseText -- текст ответа.
}
```

Comment: передаете объект вместо url? второй параметр функции [open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()) - это адрес куда делается запрос

Comment: А в send передаем obj, я теперь понял.

Comment: описался прост.